# Ubuntu 16.04 Not Booting from USB but works in VM

Tags: boot, usb

I am trying to get Ubuntu 16.04 on my USB and boot it from there. I have used a LiLi USB Creator and put Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit on it with a VM there aswell. When I run it from VM it launches and wants to do the installation process or to log me in, but I don't have an account.

But when I go into my BIOS and set it to boot from the USB it goes to the purple screen, goes to a black screen where it has the writing of what it's doing, I believe it unpacks somethings. And then my monitors stop receiving video input and i'm left with darkness and nothing happens even after 10 minutes.

I've tried doing research to find the solution but I couldn't find anything.

Black screen after this:
[image: https://gyazo.com/8b1b847da7d53cb6917ed6cfb3f8543c]

Edit:
On VM I choose to 'Try Ubuntu' but then I get a black screen.

Comment: Are you trying to boot to a LiveUSB created from an ISO image downloaded from http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/?

Comment: I didn't download it from directly there, but I downloaded the desktop version straight from Ubuntu's website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform these steps:

First configure the bios to permitt logging in without loading the drivers with the `nomodeset` grub parameter.

```
1) Boot to your Grub menu
2) Hit e to edit.
3) Find the line that begins with `linux`.  Append to this line **nomodeset**
4) Hit `F10` to save and boot.
```

Update:

To ENTER the grub menu from a legacy LiveUSB boot, **press <kbd>ESC</kbd> when the computer first start to boot to the stick**.  This will skip the GUI and give you a text option.

- Select your language (Press ENTER)
- Press <kbd>F6</kbd> (Other Options), then hit <kbd>ESC</kbd>.
- Now use the arrows to add `nomodeset` as a parameter after the words `quiet splash`.
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to continue boot with the **selected options**.

Comment: How would I boot to the Grub menu specifically.

Comment: The grub menu is what you see when you see the options **Try Ubuntu** or **Install Ubuntu**.  Select the **Try Ubuntu**, then hit **`e`** to edit and follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: I never go into the grub menu, it opens Ubuntu and then there I have the two options but I can't press e.

Comment: What are the two options you have when you boot from the LiveUSB?

Comment: I don't have any? Ubuntu launches and I get the GUI or WIMP then there I choose 'Try Ubuntu' or 'Install Ubuntu' but  it isn't the Grub menu. When I click 'Try Ubuntu' It goes back to the black screen in the image, does some things and stops on 'ata1: EH complete'. Also I have no option to press 'e'

Comment: Don't click **Try Ubuntu**.  Select it with your mouse.  **Do not Click**.  When you see this option, you are in Grub.  This is the Grub menu with those two option.  After you have selected **Try Ubuntu** without clicking hit the letter **`e`** on the keyboard.  **Do not click**.  After you have hit **`e`** without clicking, make the change that is in the answer.  The last step is **`F10`**.  Please notice, there isn't a click in the answer.  The change isn't made by a click.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5abb3f1291410d5af61670529983f6c4. It doesn't allow me to press 'e' once I've selected it.

Comment: Give me a second to run the ISO on a different computer to find the Grub Menu option from the GUI.  The UEFI enabled computers starts out in the black screen grub.

Comment: Should I re-enable UEFI in my bios? I used to do it in UEFI but then I was getting better results without UEFI so I carried on without it.

Comment: No.  Press ESC quickly to cancel the GUI.  There you will get a menu before booting.  Give me a second to update the answer with the details of this method.

Comment: Basically you go into the Language, then you hit **`F6`** to choose the option.  The option **nomodeset** option is in a dropdown menu.

Comment: @DrLlama I added the formatted steps to the answer under **Update**.

Comment: I added **nomodeset** and when I press F10 I get no video signal on my monitors again.

Comment: Okay nvm, don't answer that got it to work.